# how to access the gridview values inside the TemplateField asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to access the values of gridview which is generated dynamically. I want to that values of gridview to copy in datatable but I can not access it. My code is mention below.

```
DataTable dtCustomers = new DataTable("ShippingDetails");

//Add columns to DataTable.
foreach (TableCell cell in gvShippingBill.HeaderRow.Cells)
{
    dtCustomers.Columns.Add(cell.Text);
}
foreach (GridViewRow row in gvShippingBill.Rows)
{
    dtCustomers.Rows.Add();
    for (int i = 0; i < row.Cells.Count; i++)
    {
        // Console.WriteLine(gvShippingBill.Columns[i].ToString());
        dtCustomers.Rows[row.RowIndex][i] = gvShippingBill.SelectedRow.Cells[i].Text;
        //row.Cells[i].Text;
    }
}

return dtCustomers;
```

Comment: Why use the values of the GridView and not the original source data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 bind value in lable inside the template filed
 <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("CultivarType") %>'/>
 </ItemTemplate>

 using find control u can get that value
 Label lb = (Label)GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].FindControl("Label1");
  string s = lb.Text;
```